Dreamlandjs - Text on page not updating when stateful value changes
I am using dreamland.js to write a simple application. I expect the text in the "preview" section to update when I set the value in state, but it's not updating despite the value clearly being changed. Code is below
import "dreamland/dev";

let state = $state({
    currentText: ""
})

function Editor() {
  return (
    <div id="editor">
      <textarea
        value={state.currentText}
        on:input={(e: InputEvent) => {
          state.currentText = e.target!.value
          console.log(state.currentText)
        }}
        autofocus
      />
      <div id="preview">
        {state.currentText}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function MainApp() {
  return (
    <div id="app">
      <Editor />
    </div>
  )
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(<MainApp />)
})


In dreamland, data will not automatically update unless you tell it to, so the preview is only getting assigned the value that currentText was at when the component was created.
If you want the preview text to update as the value does, replace
<div id="preview">
   {state.currentText}
</div>

with
<div id="preview">
   {use(state.currentText)}
</div>

See https://dreamland.js.org/reactivity for more information about reactivity
